# good alternatives to corba

Tags: java, corba

can someone pleas tell a few good alternatives to corba.

Comment: It would help people answer your question if you could explain what you're trying to do, or what you're not satisfied with in Corba.

Comment: wow! i never knew people use corba.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ it's often used in industry, e.g. banking, partly this is due to legacy enterprise systems from the 90's that are still in use.

Comment: @J-16 - CORBA is used heavily in avionics, embedded systems and networks of embedded systems. The Software Defined Radio architecture (something that is big within the DoD) is specifically a CORBA-based architecture. For those markets, there aren't really any good **standardized** alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need support for more than a language [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) could be a good solution. It is widely used at Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

As per: https://cajo.dev.java.net/

The cajo project is a small, 100% Free library, enabling powerful dynamic multi-machine coöperation; both within and between, both free and proprietary Java applications. It is a surprisingly easy to use, yet completely understandable framework, unmatched in performance. It is actively being deployed in Java EE, SE, and ME environments all over the world. It is a uniquely 'drop-in' distributed computing framework: meaning it imposes no structural requirements on your applications, nor source changes. It allows multiple remote JVMs to work together seamlessly, as one.

Comment: @user581734 You could also use RMI. You would find that CAJO is easier to use, CAJO can also go through firewalls if you need to, If that is not a requirement you could use RMI.

Comment: Romain, that was very old question, so I suppose that a lot of things changed since then, and the answers might be out of date - so could you tell me - now in 2016 what java framework or technology could be used instead of corba?

Comment: @ArturArsalanov depends what services you need. Java comes with corba and rmi.HTTP is used if you must cross firewalls